# Best way to center content in android linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout

I've created the following splash screen layout using android developer studio. I wanted to center the content which consist of two text views and an image view. The following is the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splash_gradient">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView id="@+id/splashscreen"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:paddingBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_thin"
        android:paddingTop="90dp"
        android:paddingRight="90dp"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="App"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:paddingTop="90dp"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will look as following image.

[image]

Is this the correct way to center my content or is there a better way to achieve what I'm looking for? Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using padding to center the elements, it is the wrong way because you will get different results with different screens.

See this alternative, it is not the only one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_gradient"
    android:gravity="center">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/splashscreen"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:paddingBottom="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_logo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/splashscreen"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_thin"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="App"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_regular"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've changed a bit of your answer to get my exact design and it looks perfect. Could you direct me to any documentation on how to get stunning UIs with this android layouts! I've googled and found only basic tutorials.

Comment: I don't recall any tutorial in particular. But search for tutorias specific to each layout: FrameLayout, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, and ConstraintLayout. This last one is the one with more options but also the most complex so I would sugest getting familiar with the previous ones first.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

first DO NOT use padding or margin to align Views with respect to siblings views or layout, it will look great in 1 device but won't in other devices with different screen sizes. Use layout_align attribute. Learn Linear layout properties [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html). Then you will able to discover best way by your self.

my solution

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp" 
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sample"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" App"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                />

        </LinearLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```